# ReactJS importing selected const/component as all (import {test1, test2} as TST from '../comptest')

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem selecting multiple components.

this work:
`import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/Routes';`

this one doesn't, I want only to select multiple components from Routes
`import {comp1, comp2, comp3} as ROUTES from '../../constants/Routes';`

and I will pass them to a dropdown component and map() the passed ROUTES in the Dropdown component

`const DROP_DOWN_LINKS = ROUTES;
<Dropdown links={DROP_DOWN_LINKS}/>`

How do I call them like this `import {comp1, comp2, comp3} as ROUTES from '../../constants/Routes';` that will work?

Comment: that is not supported, what you can do is. create an array. insert your components into that array, and run a map on it

Comment: Hi Rei Dien. Thank you. I just did put them all in array :). and it work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Comp1, Comp2, Comp3 } from './mycomponent'

const arr = [Comp1, Comp2, Comp3]

arr.map(component => {
  // ... do whatever you want
})
```